# My own Arch Linux based distribution

Tags: arch-linux

Well, i'm looking for some book, or wiki, to create my own based distribution, I really don't know where to start, only thing that I know is: I want to make a Arch Linux distribution, not just a Live CD, or something, but my OWN distribution, I know that I'll have to study so much to get there, but I really want it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific *nix problem but a vague request for a huge amount of information most of which is easily obtainable by a web search. Please start reading up on this and post a question if you run into specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

Arch Linux is a distribution. What you want is to make your own distribution, possibly based on Arch Linux. If you're interested in creating your own distro, then I'd suggest starting with [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/) . From there you can then add things such as a package manager (e.g., pacman), and other features you like. LFS is not only a great way to get started in making your own distro, it's also an excellent way to learn the inner-workings of Linux. Have fun!

Comment: But where could I found the source code of "pacman"?

Comment: Here are some links:

[Arch git repos](https://projects.archlinux.org/)


[Pacman Source](ftp://ftp.archlinux.org/other/pacman/)

How did I find these links? I searched for "pacman source" on DuckDuckGo.

Comment: @VictorQueiroz ummm google? First hit for "arch source of pacman": https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/

Comment: Sorry guys, I will do it, thanks for everything.

Comment: @VictorQueiroz no problem. Have a look at our [help] to understand this site's scope better. Apart from that, try the Linux from Scratch and post back here if you have problems.

Comment: How much kindness, thank you. I want to help everyone in the community, and I will read the rules. See you soon.